# Calendar on Report VB.net Reporting

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

How can I display a calendar template on a  report ? The calendar has nothing to do with the data on the report - it just a calendar. I am using VB.net with reporting services.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to include a calendar as an image.